# state not being updated with api response data

Tags: reactjs, axios

My state currently contains `UserInfo` which i want to set with the data i am recieving from the api call i am making. I have done this with the following code below but the state is not being set, im not entirely sure why.

my code;

```
export class GoogleMaps extends Component {
  state = {
    UserInfo: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        self.setState({ UserInfo: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    }

  render() {
    const { UserInfo } = this.state;
    if (!UserInfo) {
      return <div>Loading Map...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={5}>
        {this.state.UserInfo.map(User => (
          <Marker
            key={User.id}
            position={{ lat: User.latitude, lng: User.longitude }}
          />
        ))}
      </Map>
    );
  }
}



export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "key"
})(GoogleMaps);
```

Im currently getting no errors, what could be the problem? any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: setState is async as is your .get query. You aren’t waiting for anything to update before logging the state. Add a callback in your setState to see the result.

Comment: @basic Yes that works, perfect, thank you